# Google Chrome Cleanup Tool for Ubuntu (Linux) like Windows?

Tags: google-chrome

There is a Google Chrome cleanup tool: [chrome/cleanup-tool/](https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/) to remove malware, fix crashes, unusual startup pages or toolbars, unexpected ads you can't get rid of, or otherwise changing your browsing experience. But the link only provides a download option for Windows.

Is there something similar for Ubuntu (Linux)? The reason I need it is I had cleaned out my Google cache and password lists to fix a problem. Now like some other users Chrome is only remembering my passwords and not User ID so I have to retype them after each boot for every website I use. One of the recommended solutions is to run the clean up tool but as stated I can only find one for Windows.

Does anyone know of something similar for Linux / Ubuntu even if it's only a beta or experimental version?

Please note this is `Chrome` and not `Chromium` as many seem to confuse the two products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of Google Chrome not auto-logging into websites was caused by an outdated copy of Chrome residing in a Windows 7 partition. When I logged onto Windows 7 a few days ago I was prompted that Chrome was out of date there and needed to be upgraded.

After upgrading Windows 7 version of Google Chrome the Old User ID's and Passwords in Google gmail, AskUbuntu stack exchange and other sites automagically started working again. I suspect this only happens when `Google Sync` option is implemented across platforms.

I hope this helps others in similar situations.

Answer (score 3):

The best option may be to remove and reinstall chrome.

```
sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable
rm -r ~/.config/google-chrome
rm -r ~/.cache/google-chrome
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

If you wanted to just remove the user config files without reinstalling run the following command:

```
rm -r ~/.config/google-chrome
rm -r ~/.cache/google-chrome/
```

Comment: I thought about that as I was writing my question and thought of putting in a qualifier "I don't feel like reinstalling Chrome" but left it out in case it was the only option. Thank you for your answer and I will accept it in a couple of days if no one else posts what I was really looking for.

Comment: You could try just removing the config files in ~/.config/google-chrome and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: Sounds like a good idea I've read something similar for pepper-flash before.  Why don't you add that to your answer and make it all-inclusive?

Comment: Just an update... removing configuration files generated uareadahead errors in boot logs. So you need to rebuild ureadahead with `sudo rm /var/lib/ureadahead/pack/`

Comment: Did you remove other configuration files besides the ones for chrome? I don't know why the google chrome configuration files would result in this?